# Alternative(s) of converting Canvas to WritableImage

Tags: java, image, canvas, javafx, snapshot

I'm developing an application which needs a lot of comparing image data in JavaFX. For that comparing, I need to to get rgb data of pixels in the images. Let's say that the picture I need to compare is **Picture1** and **Picture2**. **Picture1** is an input picture selected by the user. **Picture2** is a drawing that I make programmatically.

AFAIK, the only way to get rgb data per pixel in JavaFX is with `PixelReader` of `Image`. It's fine for the **Picture1** since it's an input. But I need to do a drawing on **Picture2** and **Picture2** is a `Canvas` (I draw polygons on Picture2 and because drawing pixel by pixel with PixelWriter is a bit complicated IMO) and doesn't have a `PixelReader` or something with similar functionality. So my solution is as follows:

1. Read input image and make Picture1
2. Make a Canvas and do the drawing
3. Attach the Canvas to a Scene
4. Make snapshot of the Scene and make WritableImage (Picture2)
5. Compare Picture1 and Picture2

So I have a method with something like:

```
public static WritableImage makeDrawableImage(Canvas in) {
     AnchorPane root = new AnchorPane(in);
     WritableImage out = new WritableImage((int)in.getWidth(), (int)in.getHeight());
     Scene sc = new Scene(root, in.getWidth(), in.getHeight());

     out = in.snapshot(null, null);

     return out;
}
```

However it takes a really long time for the snapshot to finish. The value of `out` never gets assigned. I don't know what I did wrong.

Is there any alternative to convert `Canvas` to `Image` or `WritableImage`? Or maybe there is a library to do drawing of polygons easier with `PixelWriter`?

Please be soft on me. This is my first question on Stack Overflow and I'm not a *real* programmer nor an IT student. I code as a hobby.

So, thanks in advance. Cheers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a snapshot of a canvas with this method:

```
public static WritableImage pixelScaleAwareCanvasSnapshot(Canvas canvas, double pixelScale) {
    WritableImage writableImage = new WritableImage((int)Math.rint(pixelScale*canvas.getWidth()), (int)Math.rint(pixelScale*canvas.getHeight()));
    SnapshotParameters spa = new SnapshotParameters();
    spa.setTransform(Transform.scale(pixelScale, pixelScale));
    return canvas.snapshot(spa, writableImage);     
}
```

The pixel scale normally is 1.0 unless you have a HiDPI screen.

Comment: It still doesn't work :( My problem is with the 'out = in.snapshot(null, null);' It takes really long time. Is it really take that long to make a snapshot?

Comment: What doen't work for you? How large are your images?

Comment: Obviously you are still using your code and not mine. In my code there is no line 'out = in.snapshot(null, null);' Taking a snapshot of a 2000x2000 canvas just takes milliseconds.

Comment: `return canvas.snapshot(spa, writableImage)` doesn't give anything. I think it's because it takes a long time.Is that right?. The canvas is 600x1000. Thanks anyway

Comment: If it takes so long for you, then this is suspicious. Maybe you have drawn so much into the canvas, that the rendering has not yet finished?

Comment: I found the problem with my code. I just realized that the method was ran on another thread so the `snapshot` doesn't work. Anyway thanks mipa :)